# mp3 decode error with ffmpeg in ios

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I met a very strange phenomenon in decoding mp3 to pcm data in ios pad.
I have tested the code on windows 10, it works correctly.However, with the same mp3 file and the same code runing on ios pad , the pcm data become total white noise.

I have compare the input compressed data(mp3) and the decoded data in memory on both system. input data is all the same(none silence frame),but the decoded data has totally different.

so, can I say that there is a bug in ffmpeg on ios platforms for decoding audio.the version I used is ffmpeg2.6

anyone meet the same things?

Comment: anyone who meet the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've not come across those issues you describe yet from 2.0.4 right up to 3.2 of ffmpeg.

The decoded audio in AVFrame is defined using:

```
AVFrame
    uint8_t*    data[8]         pointer to audio samples
                                Stereo S16P will use planar data not interleaved audio
    int         linesize[8]     length of each line
    int         nb_samples
    int         format          enum AVSampleFormat
    int         sample_rate     44100, 48000, etc
    int         channels        number of audio channels
```

More here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.0/structAVFrame.html

Without any information from yourself (ie your own sample code) it's hard to say why you are getting white noise.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I double check this issue on ios. there is a third part   library also referred ffmpeg inside. So the runtime call get chaos. two ffmpeg versions running on one system. So various problems come out.

Comment: Seems that ffmpeg-2.6.3 has this problem permanently,since I have remove other librarys which may cause chaos.Well, my scenario is very simple. single channel, 16bit , sample rate 32000 mp3 decoding. no need to resample. decoding is normally by calling avcodec_decode_audio4. however, output is not correct pcm comparing with the one on windows.

Comment: It might be a good idea then to rebuild the ffmpeg libraries using a different version. I hope you manage to get it fixed.

Comment: the problem is fixed in release version 2.9. I found that each version has different problems not solved. thus I can only adjust my implementing to adapt it.